# add a text field on click of a link: javascript disabled

Tags: javascript

How do I add a text field on click of a link inside a form when javascript is disabled? It should not refresh the page and should store the form values which are present earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript is disabled, the interaction should occur using a server. You should call an appropriate event on the server and this latter will return the page with an added textfield.

Comment: You will probably have to consider refreshing the page if Javascript is disabled. I do not see another valid solution otherwise. Why is Javascript disabled and why refreshing the page is not considered ?

Comment: Actually if javascript is enabled and then i m trying to add a text field its coming properly after retaining the above values within the form but if javascript is disabled then after clicking on link the text field gets added but the above values within the form also gets cleared.

Comment: Could you show us the code or explain the different technologies involved ...For the server-related event, the values should be stored in order to be displayed when the page is loaded with the new field